# Node Passport session lost on subsequent calls

Tags: node.js, passport.js

**I believe I have configured everything correctly:**

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.cookieParser('secret message')); // secret it set here in new version of express or connect
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.session());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
});
```

When the request is made to "login" **with the correct credentials:**

```
app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.passport);  // {"user":"5259f2739d4323000a000003"}
});
```

`req.session.passport` is populated:

```
"passport": {"user":"5259f2739d4323000a000003"}
```

However, when a call is made to:

```
app.post('/api/checklogin', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.passport);  // {}
})
```

`req.session.passport` is lost:

```
"passport":{}
```

Both times, `req.session` looks like this:

```
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"passport":{}}
```

** Passport object is obviously different though, as described above

I assume I have configured `serializeUser` correctly, because it correctly sets this property.

I am not completely sure how Passport creates session cookies, and how these cookies can persist.

I assume that `req.session.passport` is supposed to retain the user property, but it seems that the Passport object either:

1. Resets on every call
2. Does not actually save the Passport property in the session
3. The session is never created

I fear that I may be overlooking something large -- possibly something that I may need to do that Passport doesn't handle directly for me.

I do not know of any way to test if the session is created by Passport.

Any advice or help is really appreciated. This has been a multiple day struggle.

Comment: Can you show your `deserializeUser`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using a cluster setup?  If so, you need to stop using the default `MemoryStore`, and switch to something like [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis), so different instances of your app can access the shared session data.

Comment: I am not using a cluster-setup, should I? Why would the default MemoryStore not work. I don't believe I am creating more than one instance

Comment: Could you explain what the actual issue was? I'm running into the exact same problem, however switching to a Redis store doesn't solve the issue. The `deserializeUser` function is still never called on sequential calls, nor is the `passport` property of the session restored from the previously serialised value.